# Can I initialize a constant integer with a L-value?

Tags: c++, constants, c++14

I've got a question in my assignment that asks me to evaluate whether the following function call is correct. I'm not sure if a **const int** can be initialized with a variable of type **const int&**. I know that a const int can be initialized with another int, for example

```
int i=3; const int j=i
```

works perfectly fine, but I'm not sure if the following code is semantically correct (the line const int j=bar(++i);)

```
int foo (int& i) {return i+=2;}

const int& bar(int &i){ return i+=2;}

int main(){
   int i=5;
   const int j=bar(++i);
}
```

Comment: in any case the code is confusing. I'd rather write `const in j = 8;` or whatever is the simpler solution for your actual problem

Comment: Sure. It's just not a compile time constant any more. (Even though in this case the value can be determined at compile time.) This is not uncommon, for example when initializing constant function parameters. The main purpose of a const declaration is to express the *intent* not to change that value and prevent unintended alterations. Actual constness and potential optimizations are often secondary (and the latter not dependent on the const declaration, see http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm).

Comment: @idclev463035818 when beginners tries to learn, they will try silly thing just to understand what is working and what is not. This is part of a completely normal learning process.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot agreed. I should know that writing a question with a mcve often requires to write code that looks contrived and is unrelatstic when considered on its own. Its my comment that was silly

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can. You can initialize an object with any value category.

When constructing the type, it will simply call its constructor with the correct overload, such as `type(type&& other)` or `type(type const&)`.

For trivial types, it's always a copy. So as long as the types are compatible, no matter their value category, it will work.

Initializing a reference is different. You must have an expression with a compatible value category. For example, creating a mutable reference from your function won't work:

```
int& j = bar(++i); // won't compile, int& cannot be bound to int const&
```

This is because `bar` returns a reference to const, thus cannot be bound to a reference to mutable.

---

As a side note, even though it's an int constant, it is not a *compile time constant* anymore. Thus you won't be able to use it as an array size or template parameter.

To fix that you'd have to use `constexpr`, which will guarantee that the value of your variable is available at compile time.

```
int a = 9;
constexpr int b = a; // Won't work, `a` is a runtime value, `b` is compile time

constexpr int a = 1;
constexpr int b = a + 1; // Works! Both compile time values
```

Answer (score 0):

A reference is basically just an alias to the object it is bound to (with possible indication of immutability by `const`). Since `bar(++i)` returns a reference bound to `i`, it is the same as if you initialized `j` by `i` after `bar(++i)` call:

```
bar(++i);
const int j = i;
```

Const reference just says that you cannot modify the bound object through that reference. But there is nothing in your code that would try doing this.